# error while importing data through impex

Tags: sap-commerce-cloud, impex

I am trying to insert into ProductFeature table in which product object is used. But unable to do it. How to insert values to the below impex header?

```
insert_update ProductFeature; product(code,catalogVersion(catalog(id[default=hpeCatalog]),version[default=Staged]))[unique=true];qualifier;value[translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ProductFeatureValueTranslator] 
;J007007;abcd;efgh
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding to @dj_frunza answer, since `value` is `Object` type, you need to give object type followed by its value both separated by comma (,)

```
INSERT_UPDATE ProductFeature; product(code,catalogVersion(catalog(id[default=hpeCatalog]),version[default=Staged]))[unique=true];qualifier;value[translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ProductFeatureValueTranslator] ;
;J007007;abcd;String,efgh
```

Answer (score 1):

The value attribute expects two strings instead of one
(instead of "efgh" there should be "efgh,ijkl")
Also upper case should be used for header(i.e insert_update should be INSERT_UPDATE).
I modified the impex and bellow is the version that works for me:

```
INSERT_UPDATE ProductFeature; product(code,catalogVersion(catalog(id[default=hpeCatalog]),version[default=Staged]))[unique=true];qualifier;value[translator=de.hybris.platform.catalog.jalo.classification.impex.ProductFeatureValueTranslator] ;
;J007007;abcd;efgh,ijkl
```

Comment: I am able to insert values, but these are not coming under classification features,  instead those productfeatures available in unassignedfeatures list.